# View MS Access Report in .net ReportViewer control

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ms-access, reportviewer

Is it possible to view an MS Access report in the .Net ReportViewer control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think so...you first need to migrate the reports to SSRS. http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/sql/2000/deploy/migratereports.mspx